# How to make justify a horizontal menu without breaks?

Tags: html, css, sass, menuitem

So I'm trying to justify a horizonatl menu.

It should look like this:

[image]

So I tried this:

```
ul {

    &.nav-fixed {
    list-style: none;
    list-style-image: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position:  relaiv;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    }


    li {
        a {
          display: inline-block;
          margin: 0;
          font-weight: normal;
          color: $red;

        }
    }

}
```

And it worked. Everything is center and there are no spaces left or right.
My Problem is that "First Item" and "Last Item" are breaked. The second word is now in a new line.

I don't know how to fix that. I add **width: 100%;** to my li{} but than it is not center anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `white-space: nowrap` to any of you selectors (`ul`, `li` or `a`) for your words to keep on one line.

Answer (score 0):

Try add `white-space: nowrap;` to li